# opening an image in rails on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to open an image on click listener 
 like this
  [image]

and this should have close button also so that user can close it

i tried

```
<a class="need-help"><p>Need Help</p> <img src="<%=image_path('img/check-sample.png') %>" alt=""> </a>
```

I am thinking to append the img src tag to the anchor but i don't think it will work like the screenshot which i attached

any idea how to pop up image on the click of an anchor tag

Comment: Are you using `bootstrap`? or `foundation-zurb`? or any view-framework? If not, and you're just using jQuery, then you might be interested with [featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/). Try and click "image" on that page to see an example. You could also google "jQuery image modal" or "JS image modal" to see other alternatives.

Comment: Would suggest to look into jQuery modal, will make the work simple in case of rails

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bootstrap` you can use the [modal plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/)